# BeagleBone Black debian Image

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I have already install my own application in the Debian (BeagleBone, BeagleBone Black - 4GB SD),but i just want to make my own image with the applications installed,how to do?Many thanks!
ps:via microSD card

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on Super User: http://superuser.com - General computing hardware and software questions belong there.

Comment: What is the question on Super User?

Comment: There is no question.  My comment means to ask this on Super User instead, not here.  This isn't programming related.

Comment: I think Yocto project is answer to your question. You can create your image with Yocto project and then you can install your application in it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar and was looking into how to make a customized image for the Beaglebone Black with all the required drivers (for wifi) and applications preinstalled (apt-get, npm, pip).  I wanted to cross-compile everything from a different host computer since installing/compiling everything on the Beaglebone Black takes a long time compared to cross-compiling it.

I came across `buildroot` (https://buildroot.uclibc.org/) and it looks very promising although I haven't had time to actually try out the image I compiled.  I found this training manual for `Buildroot` that explains how to build a minimal system for the Beaglebone Black (http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-labs.pdf).

Another project I haven't tried but looked at briefly is `fwup` (https://github.com/fhunleth/fwup).  The example project (https://github.com/fhunleth/bbb-buildroot-fwup) is for the Beaglebone Black.  It seems `fwup` also uses buildroot to compile the firmware images that you can `dd` to an sdcard along with the added bonus of being able to create "firmware update images" for incremental updates to the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Flasher Image (putting Beaglebone eMMC to uSD)

As noted at the bottom of the eLinux [http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents] article, there is a much easier way if you are running the Debian distribution:

1) Boot master BBB with no SD card in

2) Insert SD card

3) Log in (e.g. with serial terminal, SSH etc.) and run sudo /opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/beaglebone-black-make-microSD-flasher-from-eMMC.sh. LEDs will flash in sequence whilst SD card is being written.

4) When the LEDs stop and the script terminates, remove the SD card.

5) Insert SD card into new BBB then power on.

eMMC will be flashed; LEDs on new BBB will flash in sequence until complete.